# Text wrapping in FlowDocument like MS Word's square layout

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I'm creating a text editor and using a `RichTextBox` with a `FlowDocument` inside. How does one go about making the text wrap around an `Image` object, similar to the square layout in MS Word. At the moment all I am able to get it to do is make the image inline with the text, which creates a big gap when the image is large. Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Inlines.Add("Hello");

BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("test.png", UriKind.Relative));
Image img = new Image();
img.Width = 50;
img.Height = 50;
img.Source = bmp;

p.Inlines.Add(img);

fld.Blocks.Add(p);
```

What do I need to change to make multiple lines of text wrap around the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use a [Figure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.figure.aspx)? The examples at the bottom show just what you said about lines of text "wrapped" around an image.